# Lock Portrait View in App Delegate while having View controller as landscape

Tags: ios, swift, landscape

I need the entire app to be locked in PortraitView, except for one view Controller. I need the functionality of these functions but I get an error for having both. When I add the view controller functions app crashes. If i take away the app delegate the view controller does what I need it too.

**App Delegate**

```
func application(_ application: UIApplication, supportedInterfaceOrientationsFor window: UIWindow?) -> UIInterfaceOrientationMask {

        return UIInterfaceOrientationMask(rawValue: UIInterfaceOrientationMask.portrait.rawValue)
    }
```

**ViewController**

```
 override var supportedInterfaceOrientations: UIInterfaceOrientationMask {
        return .landscapeRight
    }

    override var shouldAutorotate: Bool {
        return true
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Edited to use Base Controller View:**

As I can recall if the orientation is enabled for the app. The orientation functions needs to be implemented for every controller that needs to restrict it.

Alternatively, create Base UIViewController that supports `Portrait`. which should be inherited by all controllers and only override the orientation functions in the landscape controller.

**Something like the following:**

```
class BaseViewController : UIViewController {
    override var supportedInterfaceOrientations: UIInterfaceOrientationMask {
        return .Portrait...
    }
}

class ViewController1: BaseViewController {
    // nothin to override
}

class LandscapeController: BaseViewController {
    override var supportedInterfaceOrientations: UIInterfaceOrientationMask {
        return .landscapeRight
    }
}
```

Comment: into a base view controller that you should be implementing. I will add more code.

Comment: that makes abslute no sense. That is what I have above.

Comment: I have over 50 View Controllers. Im not going to add this to everyone i need it in the app delegate the way it works

Comment: you only need to add this BaseViewController instead of UIViewController. you can replace all project this ': UIViewController' with ': BaseViewController'

Comment: maybe im not fully understanding what your trying to say.

Comment: inheritance bro. create a BaseViewController that override the orientation methods with portrait orientation. all your controllers inherits it. and that landscape controller either inherit it and plus to that overrides again the orientation or it doesn't inherit it at all.

Comment: maybe you already have a BaseViewController there in your project don't you?